# java.lang.IllegalStateException: replace() called on item that was not placed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

Issue appears on multiple screens. To my surprise the same code was working for previous versions of app. I just updated the compose libraries and then all this happening again and again on multiple locations.

I am using LazyColumn to populate list items. Whenever I try to scroll it, the App crashes. Below is the abstract code, that I'm using. The issue appears after updating compose Bom version to ***2023-08-00***. The same code works for other screens. The only difference here is that the lazy column item is almost half of the screen height(1:1 aspect ratio). So mostly two items per screen.

```
val users = viewModel.usersList

val lazyColumnListState = rememberLazyListState()

val shouldStartPaginate = remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        viewModel.canPaginate && (lazyColumnListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index
            ?: -9) >= (lazyColumnListState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 9)
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(key1 = shouldStartPaginate.value) {
    if (shouldStartPaginate.value && viewModel.listState == ListState.IDLE)
        viewModel.getMoreUsers()
}
//Inside Scafold
LazyColumn(
state = lazyColumnListState,
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp),
modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
) {
    items(
        items = users,
        key = { it.userID ?: (1000..5000).random() }) { i ->
        ComposeExploreItem(i)
    }


    if (users.isNotEmpty()) {
        item {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))
        }
    }

    composeLazyColumnPagingLoader(
        viewModel.listState,
        users,
        "No users available"
    )
}
```

Here is the Crash Log.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: replace() called on item that was not placed
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate.replace(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1517)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.lookaheadReplace$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:926)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:471)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:39)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:352)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.measureAndLayout(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:908)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.measureAndLayout$default(Owner.kt:228)
                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1156)
                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:23269)
                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22133)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22089)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22089)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22089)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4513)
                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4486)
                                        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22089)
                                        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:689)
                                        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:695)
                                        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:793)
                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4789)
                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4500)
                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3687)
                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2371)
                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9297)
                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7918)
                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: Update your question with code that you implemented in LazyColumn

Comment: @Abdullah Javed Did you find any Solution. I am facing same issue after updating my libraries version

Comment: No. For me, the issue appears when I try to add space between row elements. I tried different solutions for spacing and they worked but the next moment the same code crashed again. Let me know about your issue. Maybe, I can help.

Comment: @Abdullah Javed I did not change any thing in code. just update version of compose depdencies.  after installing app it started crashing on scroll in lazyColumn

Comment: i found the issue  in this library version 
androidx.compose.material.material  

new version is in alpha. I have reverted to beta

Comment: In my opinion this issue mostly appears when constraint layout is used. Especially in LazyColumn items. Avoid constraint layout as much as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case the problem was using `ConstraintLayout` in `LazyColumn`. I didn't want to rewrite the layout and found another solution.

I updated `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose` to version `1.1.0-alpha13`. This worked for me. I'm using compose_version:1.5.4.

Answer (score 1):

After launching the app multiples times and find manually what was causing the issue. i found the problem is Constraint Layout for compose in LazyList.

Every time my app faces any bug; I found the problem is somehow releated to Constriant Layout as people building it doesnt seem to care to update it with new compose.

I thinck people should avoid using Constraint layout unless it is actually stable

Answer (score 0):

I would call this a mystery bug. I have faced this bug in different scenarios and every time a different solution worked for me. Like I have the same code base and I just updated the library version and the crash appears. Reverting the version still persists crash. Similarly, I have used constraint layout and the code works fine. But Suddenly this crash appears. I removed ConstraintLayout and used Box/Column then the issue was fixed. Now today The same crash appears on my Chat Screen. Everything is working fine. If you write some text and send it, then it will work but when the user tries to open emojis from the keyboard the app crashes. Now, I'm looking to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

While my solution isn't relevant in the case of `LazyColumn`, the bug happens due to some already drawn composable being redrawn.

In my case it happened due to me using `HorizontalPager` as in XML layouts `ViewPager` with very complex screen inside - so debugging became hell.

It can be overcome by adding `beyondBoundsPageCount` with a value to your `HorizontalPager` because default value is `0`!
I'm not sure whether it's an issue of Google Compose team or me doing something wrong but I'm sure the fix isn't as straight forward as just updating a library (for me at least, I tried upgrading and downgrading multiple times and multiple possible libraries)

Answer (score 0):

While I do still not know the source of issue, I've found way to avoid the crash by wrapping your scrollable layout into `ConstraintLayout`

such as
`ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { LazyColumn(Modifier.constraintAs(...) {...}) {...} }`

Hope it helps.

Comment: In my case the `ConstraintLayout` usage was the problem. I replaced that with some `Box` and `Row/Column` blocks and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my `LazyColumn` that is part of quite complex CollapsingToolbar implementation. But it seems that this issue is only reproducible in **debug** build. Most probably it related to some additional Compose **debug** computations that slows down entire app. In my **release** build I can not reproduce this issue while in **debug** build it reproduces every time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a problem with compose's lazy loading and remeasuring of layouts upon recomposition.

You can check my answer on the same crash issue with `LazyVerticalGrid` layout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77433700/8578497).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is appearing with foundation library

```
androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-android:1.6.0-alpha06
androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:1.6.0-alpha06
```

that is in my case included with

```
com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.33.2-alpha
```

Changing back to:

```
com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.32.0
```

fixed that issue.