# LazyColumn java.lang.IllegalStateException: replace() called on item that was not placed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm getting a crash when scrolling a **srollable** (meaning enough content to scroll) LazyColumn.
It happens only when the content inside LazyColumn is more complex - meaning it's not an element but a layout. Elements such as simple Text(text=index.toString) works just fine, even when there's like 200 of such elements.

Other strange thing about this issue is the fact that I have very similiar screen to the code that is crashing, yet that screen is not crashing.
Downgrading libraries to stable versions (outside of material3 because older version is crashing on BottomSheet) hasn't helped me either.

Currently my critical code is this:

```
LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                stickyHeader {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.05f))
                        BrandHeaderButton(
                            modifier = (if (facts.size > 0) {
                                Modifier.weight(0.45f)
                            } else Modifier.requiredSize(0.dp))
                                .zIndex(100f)
                                .animateContentSize(),
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.facts_list_generate_questions)
                        ) {
                            //controller.onGenerateQuestionsRequest()
                        }
                        Spacer(
                            modifier = (if(facts.size > 0) {
                                Modifier.weight(0.05f)
                            }else Modifier.requiredSize(0.dp))
                                .animateContentSize()
                        )
                        BrandHeaderButton(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .zIndex(100f)
                                .weight(0.45f),
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.facts_list_add_new)
                        ) {
                            facts.add(FactIO())
                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.05f))
                    }
                }
                itemsIndexed(facts) { index, fact ->
                    (interactiveStates.getOrNull(index) ?: rememberInteractiveCardState()).let { state ->
                        LaunchedEffect(state.isChecked.value) {
                            if(state.isChecked.value) {
                                selectedFactsUids.add(fact.uid)
                            }else selectedFactsUids.remove(fact.uid)
                        }
                        FactCard(
                            data = fact,
                            state = (interactiveStates.getOrNull(index) ?: rememberInteractiveCardState()),
                            requestDataSave = requestFactSave
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging for a UNCOMFORTABLY LONG TIME I found a way around it, by wrapping the LazyColumn inside

`ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { LazyColumn(...) {...} }`

So while I have a solution, I'm looking for reason WHY. Because I simply can't believe Compose libraries are this terribly built, so that most people just wait for newer version that'll fix their issue.
I can't really imagine building whole product on Jetpack Compose and facing such critical issues.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue but with a [`LazyVerticalGrid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/grid/package-summary#LazyVerticalGrid(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) and the grid was under a `Scaffold`.
The issue was that the app crashes whenever I scrolled super fast, without a traceable stack mentioning something about the look ahead and replace function.

The solution was the same as [Jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77315311/8578497) above. I wrapped the `LazyVerticalGrid` inside a `ConstraintLayout` as follows:

```
ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ...
    ) {
        val grid = createRef()
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(grid) {
                width = Dimension.matchParent
                height = Dimension.matchParent
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue. It took me hours to debug and the solution saved the day. Hopefully, they'll fix the issue with future versions of the compose foundation library.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My app throws this exception on a `LazyColumn` of `TextField`s when the bottom textfield got focused and when I added `.imePadding` on its Modifier

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Place was called on a node which was placed already
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$LookaheadPassDelegate.onNodePlaced$ui_release
```

My `LazyColumn` looks like this

```
LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .then(modifier)
                .clickable(
                    enabled = todoItems.isEmpty(),
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null,
                    onClick = { onNewItemCreate(0) },
                )
                .imePadding()
```

The fix is wrapping the `LazyColumn` with a `ConstraintLayout`. Version `1.0.1` works for me.

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .then(modifier)
        .clickable(
            enabled = todoItems.isEmpty(),
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = null,
            onClick = { onNewItemCreate(0) },
        )
        .imePadding()
) {
    val (column) = createRefs()
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(column) {
            width = Dimension.matchParent
            height = Dimension.matchParent
        },
    ) 
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the `ConstraintLayout` library from `1.0.1` to `1.1.0-alpha13` fixed the crash for me.